# How can I make a player swims in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection

I'm creating a Java game similar to Mario Bros. I'm using Tiled Map Editor to create the map, inside the map there is water. I want to make my character swims inside water, for instance, changing the animation and make it floats. But, my character just sinks. I don't know how to implement these things inside my program, although, I succeed with collision.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Could you provide some details on how you are detecting whether the player is in water at the moment? Is Tiled Map Edtiro just a graphics tool, or does it add meta-data on which tiles should are "swimmable" as well? If it's just a graphics tool, I suspect you might be lacking code to specify those tiles are for swimming and not for walking.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `boolean inWater;` for your player and every update it checks if he is colliding with a water tile. Then in your `update` / `tick` method where you calculate your logic you just base your logic on the `inWater` variable.

For example:

```
if(inWater) {
    gravity = -0.5f;
} else if(!inWater) {
    gravity = -0.9f;
}
```

Same goes for your animations. When applying the current animation check the `inWater` variable and if it is `true`, set the `moveLeft` and `moveRight` animations to `swimRight` and `swimLeft` etc.

And to get the tile, just do what you do for collision, but instead apply it to check for water.

This is a really simple way of doing it, but googling a little won't hurt you.